# Declaring variables and select statement in a procedure

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm writing a SQL procedure which should use calculated date stored as a local variable in a select statement. I'm using Oracle SQL developer. My code is:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE 
                                   my_procedure
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
  l_max_dt  DATE;
BEGIN
 SELECT MAX(TRX_DT)
 INTO   l_max_dt
 FROM   TABLE
 WHERE 1=1;
end;
 select * from TABLE where trx_dt = l_max_dt;
end;
```

This code gives me an error : " Error(14,48): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "L_MAX_DT": invalid identifier" when select statement is present.
How can I store variables to use them in statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you write a `Procedure`. `Syntax` is `incorrect`. Read about syntax [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure
AS
   l_max_dt   DATE;
   v_var      TABLE2%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT MAX (TRX_DT)
     INTO l_max_dt
     FROM TABLE1
    WHERE 1 = 1;

   -- Assuming the query will retrun only 1 row. 
   SELECT *
     INTO v_var
     FROM TABLE2
    WHERE trx_dt = l_max_dt;
END;
```

Comment: How do I use a select statement with l_max_dt?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is one of scope. In your procedure, you have a nested block, in which you declare the l_max_dt variable. Once the code has exited that block, the l_max_dt variable is no longer in scope - i.e. the outer block does not know anything about it.

There is no need to have a nested block in this instance - you can do it all in the same block, like so:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE my_procedure
AS
  l_max_dt  DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(TRX_DT)
  INTO   l_max_dt
  FROM   TABLE
  WHERE 1=1;

--  commented out as this isn't valid syntax; there is a missing INTO clause
--  select *
--  from TABLE where trx_dt = l_max_dt;
END my_procedure;
```

However, you could simply do the query in one fell swoop - e.g.:

```
select *
from   your_table
where  trx_dt = (select max(trx_dt) from your_table);
```

A couple of points about your procedure:

1. In PL/SQL, if you use an implicit cursor (i.e. when you put a select statement directly in the body of the code) you need to have something to put the results into. You could bulk collect the results into an array, or you could ensure that you will receive exactly one row (or code error handling for NO_DATA_FOUND and TOO_MANY_ROWS) into a record or corresponding scalar variables.
2. You shouldn't use `select *` in your procedure - instead, you should explicitly state the columns being returned, because someone adding a column to that table could cause your procedure to error. There are exceptions to this "rule", but explicitly stating the columns is a good habit to get into.